# Using FileZilla and Wordpress, my index page isn't shown

Tags: php, wordpress, filezilla

I'm using FileZilla to put Wordpress on my website.
This Website already existed and already had some pages in it, and it does a backup everyday.
Unfortunately I can't delete `index.html` on the backup folder, so even if I use Wordpress to edit themes et cetera, THAT `index.html` is shown when i go visit the web site.

In the Wordpress folders there isn't a `index.html` file, only a `index.php` file, is it normal?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is normal because Wordpress uses PHP for dynamic pages.

You can add this to your `htaccess` to prefer `.php` over `.html`

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
```

Or set your wordpress Site in a sub directory of your regular site.

Comment: I'm sorry, where do i find my htaccess?

Comment: its a hidden file, if you are using linux, you can just press ctrl+h

Comment: @Ales Or you can just make a file named `.htaccess` and add it to your root of the website (where your index.html and index.php are)